# Wagtail CMS APIv2 Pagination not Showing Numbers or Next & Previous

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, wagtail

I can't seem to get pagination to work with my Wagtail CMS projects API. It only shows a random list of 20 on the page, image or documents. My code is listed below from my settings file.  The [Wagtail Documents](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.11.1/advanced_topics/api/v2/configuration.html#enable-the-app) mention just adding `rest_framework` to the settings file to allow browsing but I can't seem to figure out how to browse all and not just 20 results.  Thank you.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100,
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
    ),
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the URL parameters detailed at http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.11.1/advanced_topics/api/v2/usage.html#pagination ?

Comment: That works in allowing me to see more, but only after I set an arbitrarily high number using `WAGTAILAPI_LIMIT_MAX = 1000`.  If I set it to `None` per the docs, I get the following error `TypeError at /api/v2/pages/ unorderable types: NoneType() < int()`. I know this may be a different subject now and am happy to create a different SO question.

Comment: Sounds like this might be a Wagtail bug. I've opened this issue to cover it now: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/3766